# How to load json file from the inside of other json file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have files.json like this

```
{
    "apple": "apple789121.json",
    "banana": "banana537332.json",
    "cherry": "cherry236832.json"
}
```

I want to load json on javascript, like

```
var fruit = apple;
$.getJSON("files.json", function(data){
    //if key of files.json same with fruit variable
    if(data.key == fruit){
        //load json based on value of key
        $.getJSON(data.fruit, function(result){
            console.log("success");
        })
    }
})
```

Anyone help me please, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the example from https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

```js
var fruit = "apple";
$.getJSON("files.json", function (data) {
  $.each(data, function (key, val) {
    if (key === fruit) {
      $.getJSON(val, function (result) {
        console.log("success");
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can check if the object i.e : apple..etc exist inside json or not .Then , use `Object.values` to get value of that object and pass same to your *$.getJSON*.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//suppose this is return..
var data = {
  "apple": "apple789121.json",
  "banana": "banana537332.json",
  "cherry": "cherry236832.json"
}

var fruit = "banana";
/*$.getJSON("files.json", function(data) {*/
//if that key exist
if (Object.keys(data).indexOf(fruit) > -1) {
  //get values..
  var files = Object.values(data)[Object.keys(data).indexOf(fruit)]
  console.log(files)
  //pass here
  /* $.getJSON(files, function(result) {
   })*/
}
/*})*/
```